# In KK theory, is proper time defined using the 5 dimensional or the 4 dimensional line element?

Tags: general-relativity, time, metric-tensor, compactification, kaluza-klein

Let's consider five dimensional [KK theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kaluza%E2%80%93Klein_theory). This is Klein's metric

$\hat{g}_{AB}=
\begin{pmatrix}
g_{00}+A_{0}A_{0}&g_{01}+A_{0}A_{1}&g_{02}+A_{0}A_{2}&g_{03}+A_{0}A_{3}&A_ 0\\
g_{10}+A_{1}A_{0}&g_{11}+A_{1}A_{1}&g_{12}+A_{1}A_{2}&g_{13}+A_{1}A_{3}&A_ 1\\
g_{20}+A_{2}A_{0}&g_{21}+A_{2}A_{1}&g_{22}+A_{2}A_{2}&g_{23}+A_{2}A_{3}&A_ 2\\
g_{30}+A_{3}A_{0}&g_{31}+A_{3}A_{1}&g_{32}+A_{3}A_{2}&g_{33}+A_{3}A_{3}&A_3\\
A_{0}&A_{1}&A_{2}&A_{3}&1
\end{pmatrix}$

my question is the following, is proper time defined using the five dimensional line element?

$d\tau^2=\sqrt{-\hat{g}_{AB}dx^{A}dx^{B}}$

or is it defined as usual using the 4 dimensional line element?

$d\tau^2=\sqrt{-g_{\mu\nu}dx^{\mu}dx^{\nu}}$

in either case, why?

Comment: i have a reference somewhere of Pauli's Theory of Relativity which discusses Kaluza-Klein theory (i have to find it somewhere), until then, i would say proper time is defined as usual ($g_{\mu\nu}$ metric), since the fifth dimension in KK acts as a solenoid loop for electromagnetic potential and is "invisible" to the manifold

Comment: @NikosM. that reference would be woderful. I also feel that it surely is defined using the 4 dimensional metric but I don't really have a strong argument for that

Comment: yeap, i have it stashed somewhere, looking for it and will update

Comment: found the book, had only a passing reference to unified field theories (e.g Weyl's KK and Projective) and not much about apllications involving proper time (although in original KK, 5th dimension is taken as "cylindrical" so does not affect other 4 dimensions), the classic Bergmann text on theory of relativity (plus KK and other theories) is available online [here](https://archive.org/details/IntroductionToTheTheoryOfRelativityPart1) (parts 1-4)

Comment: i would stand by my 1st comment that "proper time" (in 4-spacetime) is still defined using 4-metric ($g_{\mu\nu}$), since in KK this 4-spacetime is still the "physical spacetime", one can still define a proper time in 5-spacetime, but would not reflect the "physical/experienced proper time" in Einstein's sense of GR, hope this is good argument (note that unified field theories like KK **do not** derive new physical results, so what holds for GR still holds for KK theory, one just has the EM field in the geometry)